# 2 JS functions with same name conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, twitter-bootstrap

## Short

Using 2 libraries at same page: jQuery UI and Twitter Bootstrap:

- jQuery UI very important for me because nearly all UI things built based on it
- Twitter Bootstrap only for [split button with dropdown menu](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton) functionality.

Now, the problem is both libraries has same named functions which conflicts with each other:

## Detailed

***Here is example of conflict between jQuery UI and Twitter Bootstrap button functions***

Please enter [to this website](http://ecruting.tisoft.me/). Press Recommend button on table

[image]

jQuery UI modal window will appear. I used [jquery ui combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) inside modal window. The problem is, there is no down arrow button as shown on [jquery ui combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) demo.

[image]

I tried to find what causes the problem: Looked through combobox code, and when it called .button() it went into bootstrap.min.js, not jqui.js.

As you see it's proof of conflict between 2 js libraries.

Btw, Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBXRn/) where it works well without bootstrap.

## Problem

I have multiple ways to solve this conflict problem (WITHOUT TOUCHING FUNCTIONALITY OF THE WEBSITE) I need to get exactly same functionality as [split button with dropdown menu (Twitter Bootstrap):](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)

- if possible in jQuery-UI (something like [this](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton) but with dropdown menu)
- else in CSS + HTML only

and get rid off Twitter Bootstrap. Any solutions greatly appreciated. I'm ready to give 200 reps to good answer (as bounty). Thx in advance

Comment: Truth be told, Twitter Bootstrap is not specially crafted to work with jQuery UI or other frameworks. For example, Twitter Bootstrap applies rules to bare elements and this will conflict the rules of jQuery UI. I think your best shot is *namespacing* Twitter Bootstrap both JS and CSS but this will require a lot of effort. So, porting that functionality to jQuery UI is better way

Answer (score 12):

The current version of bootstrap (v2.2.2) now has a noConflict option. Just insert this some place after your bootstrap and jquery script tags but before any usage of the `button()` function.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.fn.bootstrapBtn = $.fn.button.noConflict();
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use `$(document).ready(handler)`, but you still have to make sure substitution occurs before `button()` is called.

Once that line of code is executed, `button()` will be JqueryUI's button, and `bootstrapBtn()` will be Bootstrap's version.

Comment: Worked for me.  I was having a similar conflict with ui-dialog-titlebar-close x icon not appearing in the close button and bootsrap button. Easiest solution if you're using the latest of everything as of January 2013

Comment: For me this only worked if I put the code in just before loading jquery-ui.js, NOT just before my first instance of button() usage.

Answer (score 8):

To fix the collision between Bootstrap and jQuery UI functions, rename one of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.bsbutton = $.fn.button;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And then you can call each function at will:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button-one").button()   // jQueryUI button
    $(".button-two").bsbutton()  // Bootstrap button
</script>
```

You can use this technique for any function you need.

Remember the order `include A -> rename A -> include B`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the dropdown plugin of Twitter Bootstrap, you don't need the `.button()` plugin.

Go to the [customize bootstrap page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#plugins) and unselect all jQuery plugins, then choose only the dropdown one. You could also unselect some of the CSS if you want.

---

If you need both implementations (Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery UI), you could rename all `.button` to something like `.bsButton` in [the `bootstrap-button.js` file](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.1/js/bootstrap-button.js) (or find this section in a non-minified version) - not tested.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers fixing conflict between jQuery UI button and bootstrap button but you can't use bootstrap data-api for renamed `button()` function. Only manually using new-named `bootstrapBtn()` function.

I find a solution:

- Find and replace all occurences of regex `(\$[.\w]+\.)button` to `\1btn` in `bootstrap.js` file.
- Or use this `sed` script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # Change bootstrap3 $.fn.button() function to $.fn.btn() for no conflict with jQuery UI
  sed "s/\(\$[[:alnum:]._]\+\.\)button/\1btn/g" bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.btn.js
  sed "s/\(fn\.\)button/\1btn/g" bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js | sed "s/button\((\)/btn\1/g" > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.btn.min.js
  ```

After that you can use bootstrap data-api for button binding and also manually use `btn()` function in place of `button()` for Bootstrap while still use jQuery UI `button()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do custom jQueryUI, or Bootstrap build - both offer this possibility on websites.

I use custom build of jQueryUI with core, effects, interactions, but without widgets, which often causes conflicts.