# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>" title="Go Home" data-placement="bottom" rel="tooltip"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
```

And then in a external file a have this code:

```
function showtooltip() {
    $('a[rel="tooltip"], button[rel="tooltip"], input[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        animation: true
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   showtooltip();
});
```

But tooltip aren't showed. I include jquery (latest 2.0.0) and also complete TB (2.3.1) where is the problem? (please take a look at second edit maybe there is the problem)

**EDIT** I also has included this CSS files:

```
<link href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So I think CSS isn't the problem

**EDIT2** I'm using jQuery UI latest (1.10.2) and aparently JS and CSS from jQuery UI are overwriting Twitter Bootstrap. This are the lines where I include CSS (JS are included at bottom for performance)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/stylesheet/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/catalog/view/theme/viaenvia/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
```

How can avoid this?

Comment: Most common problem I have seen is that people have forgotten to include the CSS for the tooltip.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Will the tooltip work if you implement it without using custom JS?

Comment: @AGoodDisplayName I include jQuery also from Google CDN and I get TB from his [site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: @Mooseman no, this is the problem I don't get any error so I don't know where to look for mistakes

Comment: @m90 what you mean with custom JS?

Comment: You should be able to use all of Bootstrap's plugins just by declaring the behavior in your markup, so basically all you would have to do is include the corresponding js file and alter your markup.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample code is working (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3447/)), so it's probably a missing javascript reference.

For using the tooltip you need to include `bootstrap.js` (with all plugins) or at least the `bootstrap-tooltip.js` (see options on [customize download page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html)), after the reference to jquery.

*(after user comments below)*

I would recommend checking two things now:

- at the `Net` tab, try to find the request for `bootstrap.min.js` file and see if it completed successfully
- at the `Console` tab, run that selector `$('a[rel="tooltip"], ...` to see if it finds the  tags; if it does, you should be able to call something like `$('#element').tooltip('show')` to test the tooltip was successfully loaded.

Comment: You showed the references to bootstrap css files. What about the js file, did you check the reference is there - and that the <script> tag is *after* jquery's tag?

Comment: @Reynier so please create your sample in fiddle to help us find your problem.

Comment: @FelipeCastro it's included too, see [this image](http://www.dropmocks.com/mBsECs) for more info

Comment: I see it is referenced in the html, not that it's included for sure (it could be pointing to a wrong path). Please see my edit above

Comment: @FelipeCastro answering your questions `bootstrap` is loading fine, I don't know how to run the code you leave `$('#element').tooltip('show')` or don't understand your point here. I think I found where the problem is. I'm using jQuery UI too and in newest release [**tooltip** element](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) is present so in some way CSS and JS from jQuery UI are overwriting TB, any help on this?

Comment: You're right, they're using the same method name and conflicting. You have 2 ways out of this: use `.noConflict()` method - [see answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550760/2-js-functions-with-same-name-conflict) - or download jquery ui **without** the tooltip plugin (remove it at the [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/))